# Deep concept of Rotation Dynamics

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, vectors, angular-velocity

If angular velocity about axis of rotation passing through COM  is × then why value of angular velocity remains same( i.e ×) If we assume axis of rotation anywhere which parallel to the original one?

Comment: I think what you mean is that the angular variables of all points in a body which is under rotation, remains same. Is that correct?

Comment: 

Comment: What? Please type instead of using emojis.

Comment: Your question is very unclear

Answer (score 0):

It really isn't. All angular properties (displacement, velocity, acceleration, inertia, torque, momentum and energy) are defined with respect to an axis of rotation. Every single one of them includes the radius in their definition and if you move the assumed axis then your results will change accordingly.

What you will find is that in general they can be expressed as a vector in the direction of the axis of rotation. It might be the properties of vectors that could be leading to confusion here, but there is always a frame of reference and it will affect your values.